# cPanel Unable to get user id for user

Tags: cpanel

I have three server, we will call them Ebonroc, Anzu and Onyx.

All Three are running the same version of Redhat and the same version of cPanel/WHM.

Onyx is a remote server and the other two are local.

When I try and copy and account using the WHM "Copy an Account From Another Server" tool from Onyx to Ebonroc it fails with only this error. (Unable to get user id for user $Username at /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/pkgacct line 155. Command failed with exit status 255).

If I copy the same account from Onyx to Anzu it will work, and it will also work if i then copy the same account from Anzu to Ebonroc after it has been transferred to Anzu but it will never work from Onyx to Ebonroc.

Both Ebonroc and Anzu are behind the same firewall and i do not see anything being blocked during either servers attempts.

Does anyone have an idea why I can’t transfer between Onyx and Ebonroc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double check that the account name (cPanel username) is exist in the server Onyx.

> try grep user_name /etc/trueuserdomains

And see that that account exists. If you sure that the account user_name is exists, then try taking the backup of the account manually

> /scripts/pkgacct user_name

If you are still getting error as mentioned above, then check /etc/passwd file

> grep user_name /etc/passwd

You should see a line starting like as below

> user_name:x:uuu:ggg::/home/user_name:/bin/bash

Instead of /bin/bash you may see /usr/local/cpanel/bin/noshell if you haven't enabled the shell access for the account

uuu >> userID

ggg >> groupID

If you are not getting any o/p for the "grep user_name /etc/passwd", Then the account isn't created correctly.

If the account doesn't created correctly, cPanel can't detect the corresponding details.

Let us know with your results.

Comment: this response is so much more than just the answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for the detailed answer. I was able to resolve the problem but i forgot to get beck here to post that i did and for that I'm sorry.